# Managing notation in long document

Tags: symbols

I'm writing a long document with a lot of math in it. While I write, I would like to be able to keep track of whether I've used a certain symbol before or not. I tried making a table, but I gave up at 2 pages. Is there a better way to do this in latex?

Edit: I'll try the nomencl and glossary packages like you guys suggest. The example output in the documentation looks nice. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Indexing the symbols with the  `nomencl` package you could print the list of used symbols with references to pages and/or equations where they appear.

Comment: There is also `glossaries` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, the packages `nomencl` or `glossaries` are able to give you what you need.